# Completion when program has sub-commands

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I have written a command-line tool that uses sub-commands much like Mercurial, Git, Subversion &c., in that its general usage is:

```
>myapp [OPTS] SUBCOMMAND [SUBCOMMAND-OPTS] [ARGS]
```

E.g.

```
>myapp --verbose speak --voice=samantha --quickly "hello there"
```

I'm now in the process of building Zsh completion for it but have quickly found out that it is a very complex beast. I have had a look at the `_hg` and `_git` completions but they are very complex and different in approach (I struggle to understand them), but both seem to handle each sub-command separately.

Does anyone know if there a way using the built in functions (`_arguments`, `_values`, `pick_variant` &c.) to handle the concept of sub-commands correctly, including handling general options and sub-command specific options appropriately? Or would the best approach be to manually handle the general options and sub-command?

A noddy example would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Writing completion scripts for `zsh` can be quite difficult. Your best bet is to use an existing one as a guide. The one for Git is way too much for a beginner. You can use this repo:

https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions

As for your question, you have use the concept of `state`. You define your subcommands in a list and then identify via `$state` which command you are in. Then you define the options for each command. You can see this in the completion script for `play`. A simplified version is below:

```bash
_play() {
  local ret=1

  _arguments -C \
    '1: :_play_cmds' \
    '*::arg:->args' \
  && ret=0

  case $state in
    (args)
       case $line[1] in
         (build-module|list-modules|lm|check|id)
           _message 'no more arguments' && ret=0
         ;;
         (dependencies|deps)
           _arguments \
             '1:: :_play_apps' \
             '(--debug)--debug[Debug mode (even more informations logged than in verbose mode)]' \
             '(--jpda)--jpda[Listen for JPDA connection. The process will  suspended until a client is plugged to the JPDA port.]' \
             '(--sync)--sync[Keep lib/ and modules/ directory synced. Delete unknow dependencies.]' \
             '(--verbose)--verbose[Verbose Mode]' \
             && ret=0
         ;;
       esac
   esac
```

(If you are going to paste this, use the original source, as this won't work).

It looks daunting, but the general idea is not that complicated:

- The subcommand comes first (`_play_cmds` is a list of subcommands with a description for each one).
- Then come the arguments. The arguments are built based on which subcommand you are choosing. Note that you can group multiple subcommands if they share arguments.

With `man zshcompsys`, you can find more info about the whole system, although it is somewhat dense.

Comment: That is fantastic thank you so much. I'm glad you said `zshcompsys` is dense as I was starting to think it was me ;)

Comment: In 20 years this code will look like binary does to me today.

Answer (score 1):

I found a technique that works well and is easy to understand. Basically, you create a new completion function for each subcommand and call it from the top-level completion function. Here's an example with `dolt`, showing how `dolt` completes to `dolt table` and `dolt table` completes to `dolt table import`, which then completes with a set of flags:

```bash
_dolt() {
    local line state

    _arguments -C \
               "1: :->cmds" \
               "*::arg:->args"
    case "$state" in
        cmds)
            _values "dolt command" \
                    "table[Commands for copying, renaming, deleting, and exporting tables.]" \
            ;;
        args)
            case $line[1] in
                table)
                    _dolt_table
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
    esac
}

_dolt_table() {
    local line state

    _arguments -C \
               "1: :->cmds" \
               "*::arg:->args"
    case "$state" in
        cmds)
            _values "dolt_table command" \
                    "import[Creates, overwrites, replaces, or updates a table from the data in a file.]" \
            ;;
        args)
            case $line[1] in
                import)
                    _dolt_table_import
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
    esac
}

_dolt_table_import() {
    _arguments -s \
               {-c,--create-table}'[Create a new table, or overwrite an existing table (with the -f flag) from the imported data.]' \
               {-u,--update-table}'[Update an existing table with the imported data.]' \
               {-f,--force}'[If a create operation is being executed, data already exists in the destination, the force flag will allow the target to be overwritten.]' \
               {-r,--replace-table}'[Replace existing table with imported data while preserving the original schema.]' \
               '(--continue)--continue[Continue importing when row import errors are encountered.]' \
               {-s,--schema}'[The schema for the output data.]' \
               {-m,--map}'[A file that lays out how fields should be mapped from input data to output data.]' \
               {-pk,--pk}'[Explicitly define the name of the field in the schema which should be used as the primary key.]' \
               '(--file-type)--file-type[Explicitly define the type of the file if it can''t be inferred from the file extension.]' \
               '(--delim)--delim[Specify a delimiter for a csv style file with a non-comma delimiter.]'
}
```

I wrote a full guide here:

https://www.dolthub.com/blog/2021-11-15-zsh-completions-with-subcommands/