# Completing options of the form --<option>:<file> and --<option>:<possible values>

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I'm trying to write a completion method for fsharpi (F# interactive), which has options like the following:

```
--use:<file>              Use the given file on startup as initial input
--debug:{full|pdbonly}    Specify debugging type: full, pdbonly. ('full' is the default and enables attaching a debugger to a running program).
--warn:<n>                Set a warning level (0-5)
```

I'm guessing this has to be handled with *$state* similarly to [sub-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000698/completion-when-program-has-sub-commands), but the documentation is monolithic and the language isn't very descriptive, so I've gotten nowhere with experimentation and by stitching together different examples.

A solution to this would also work for aspell, which uses an equals-sign instead of the colon e.g.

```
--conf=<str>              main configuration file
```

Comment: This is actually the simplest form of completion. What you need is `_arguments`. I suggest the tutorial from zsh-users: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org, which is at least a little bit more understandable. Examples also help a lot (abound in the linked repo).

Comment: @4ae1e1 I'm not so sure that this is true. What I'm trying to have it complete is firstly `fsharpi TAB` to `fsharpi --use:` and then `fsharpi --use:TAB` to  `fsharpi --use:script.fsx`.

Comment: "I'm not so sure that this is true." What is not true? I suggested `_arguments` and a tutorial. I didn't make any falsifiable claims, except that this is easy (which is relative and not falsifiable).

Comment: What I tried to say was that I didn't think `_arguments` could complete something with a colon between the options and the actions. Maybe `_arguments` is more complex than I thought, but I'll need an exact example otherwise I'm still not getting it.

Comment: Just quote colons with backslash. Anyway, I'll post an exact answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the most common forms of completion, and it can be easily handled by `_arguments`. Note that literal colons in options can be quoted with a backslash. Here's the code example:

```
#compdef command

arguments=(
    '--use\:-:initial input file:_files'
    '--debug\:-:debugging type:(full pbonly)'
    '--warn\:-:warning level:(0 1 2 3 4 5)'
)

_arguments -S $arguments[@]
```

Reference: [`_arguments` in official documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-completion-system_002c-utility-functions).

Comment: Works like a charm :) thanks! I knew you could escape the colons with backslash, but I didn't know that `<option>:-:<description>:<action>` would work like that. I thought `_arguments` only created completions where `<option>` and `<action>` were be separated by a space.

Comment: I've linked to the official documentation. Look at the various forms of `optspec`. It's very flexible.

Comment: Oh i get it now! The '-' at the end of the name of the option (as in `--use\:-`) makes the first argument come directly after the option (no space). That's just what I was missing.